# Convert file to 24bit bitmap

Tags: imagemagick

I'm using imagemagick convert to convert this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4z85.jpg to a bmp. However for some reason the tool I am using doesn't like the bitmap. If I save the image as a png and convert it to a 24bit bmp its fine. I tried using the following command bit it doesn't like it.

```
convert -verbose  -depth 8 -type truecolor infile outfile.bmp
```

Looking at the file I see that the 'bad' bmp has

```
BMÊp1 (0's) Š
```

The good one has

```
BMvp1 (0's) 6
```

Comment: What does "doesn't like" mean? Error messages? Corruption? What's the name of this tool? Can you provide (upload) examples of both bitmaps? [maybe not to imgur, since they might reencode it].

Answer (score 1):

I have had some trouble with BMP conversions too.  I have typically specified `BMP3:outfile.bmp` and I normally get 24 bit BMP files.  sometimes I get an 8 bit BMP when converting JPEG files.  I just tried the `-type truecolor` (having seen it here) and now it looks like I get a 24 bit BMP in the cases where I used to get only 8 bits.

I also use these switches:

`-units PixelsPerInch -density 72 -compress None -depth 24`

the `-depth 24` should do a 24 bit BMP (the depth -8 in your case may also be causing a problem) but as I said I sometimes get 8 bits even with the 24 specified.

the `-units` and `-density` cases corrected a problem where sometimes I would get a 0 for the `biXPelsPerMeter` and `biYPelsPerMeter` fields in the BMP header (it did not seem to cause a problem though).  by the way I have not found a good explanation of these 2 fields.

the `-compress None` was required because sometimes a conversion generated a compressed BMP - no logical reason for doing that was found.

hopefully this will be of some help but I am not an expert on this subject - I just tried a few things and looked around using Google and came up with the above switch settings.